# find time complexity for given recurrence relation T(n)=T(√n)+n

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

can someone help me with this

given recurrence relation `T(n)=T(√n)+n`

I need to evaluate its time complexity.
I did the following:

```
given T(n)=T(√n)+n
        =>T(n-1)=T(√(n-1))+(n-1)  
        T(n)=T(sqrt(n-1))+(n-1)+n; 
        similarily evaluated T(n-2),
        T(n-3),.......

        => T(n)=T(√(n-k))+(n-k)+(n-(k-1))+.......+(n-1)+n
         assumed n-k=0
        =>n=k;
        =>T(n)=T(√(k-k))+(n-(n-1))+(n-(n-2))+......+(n-1)+n
        =>T(n)=T(0)+1+2+3+......+n
        =>T(n)=base case + Σn
        =>T(n)=constant + n(n+1)/2
        =>T(n)=O(n^2)
```

is this correct ?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Although you've posted your efforts so far, I think you'll find it hard to get help with homework on StackOverflow. I think I speak for the community when I say we mainly love to solve problems that we know might help out other developers when they're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer [here](https://qr.ae/TWsy7k) you can substitute:

[image: dfs]

so we have: [image: fgdfg]

Then the recurrence will be like:

[image: sfdgfdg]

Then we can change the representation:

[image: fg]

and according to the third case of [Master's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) the time complexity will be: [image: dfg]

Comment: rather than substituting S(k)=T(2^k) shouldnt we substitute 2^k with say p therefore itll be

Comment: @vr101I don't understand what you mean by -